# Removing the empty space - 100% CSS HTML Page

Tags: html, css

I have just managed to get a website up and running which is based on style.css

CSS FILE CODE IS AS

```
html 
{
    height:100%;
}
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  cursor:default;
  overflow:visible;
}

body
{
  padding: 0; 
  margin:0;
  color: #000000;
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  background-color: #D3D8FD;
  background-image: url('images/Bottom_texture.jpg');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: top center;
  min-width: 820px;
}

.cleared
{
  display:block;
  clear: both;
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  font-size: 0;
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

I am unable to understand that how I can change this value so when the page is opened on a big screen the empty space ans 100% stretch horizontally is not there. I just need the actual size of the page. SO the empty space is not left.
I have read all about the css here but couldn't get an appropriate code because I am not so good in it.

Thank you.

Comment: post the html you are using. Without it, it's more difficult to see what your css is doing.  Secondly, if you can add a screenshot of what your page looks like, and a picture of how you want it to look, you'll get much better help.

Comment: At the beginning of your CSS document, you have an HTML selector, and then a set of rules with no selector, is this a typo?

Comment: Please see the live site [link] (http://eastlondonlpg.co.uk) . Look at the space in the body of those pages. I need to remove the empty spaces on all the page body so the footer can come where the writing ends. But if you open it in small screen it shows less space. I have been trying since a week now and cannot get it right. thank you

Comment: @Kylie I am sorry but I am not good with code and all this stuff. just some knowledge how its done. So if you could look at actual live site [link](http://eastlondonlpg.co.uk) that might be help full for you to understand. Ty

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do....

This should work with the code you have, making html and body 100% height, but you need to also add

```
div#yourdiv { 
  height:100% 
}
```

For whatever div you want to take the entire 100% height of the browser window.

Comment: I have tried using that but I have not been able to get it right. I have realized that the website when opened in small screen laptops gives different height. SO i saw this 100% CSS code. That might be the issue. But I don't want to have 100% rather where the body text ends the footer should come. Ty

Comment: Ah, ok, so you want the footer to take the remaining space at the bottom?  Or do you want the footer to be a fixed size, and have the body come all the way down to the footer?

Comment: Hi, Actually My Issue is that the website height is been 100% of the screen. I need the body to finish where the text or images end and then there should eb footer than the empty space and then the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Updated code, replace all your code with this:

**CSS**

```
{ 
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  left: 0; 
  top: 0; 
  cursor:default; 
  overflow:visible; 
}     
body 
{ 
  padding: 0;  
  margin:0; 
  color: #000000; 
  background-color: #D3D8FD; 
  background-image: url('images/Bottom_texture.jpg'); 
  background-repeat: repeat-x; 
  background-attachment: fixed; 
  background-position: top center; 
  min-width: 820px; 
} 
.cleared 
{ 
  display:block; 
  clear: both; 
  float: none; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  border: none; 
  font-size: 0; 
  height:0; 
  overflow:hidden; 
}
```

Hope this is what you're looking for...

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Actually you guys are miss understood what I am trying to do is.
I need to remove the 100% CSS height option so I can get the pages not to be displaying all the height of the browser. 

I need to have the page height end where the page text, and body ends... so the footer comes and on big screens its often left blank. ty

Comment: Got it, ok that's easy then, I edited the code above.  It's easy, just remove anything that says "height" or "min-height" from the code you posted...

Comment: Hi I have tried doing wat you asked me to do. But it still is same and I have not been able to help the full height thing. I have removed the syntax on my demo site but it still shows.. 100% height on the browzer.. and on large screed it givess a big white gap. Which I want to remove...

Comment: Can you post a link to the site?  Or at least edit your original post and add the html as well?  It would make it much easier to try to figure out without guessing.

Comment: Link to the website is [link](http://eastlondonlpg.co.uk) You can get the source CSS from there. I tried the above suggestions for removing the 100% height attrib. But Unfortunately it didn't work. Although there is nothing wrong but the current layout is not helping. As the site has different size pages I cannot change the height to a static size. But want to remove the empty space after the body text and the footer. So the footer can start where the body container data ends.

Comment: The problem isn't the CSS.  You need to clean up your HTML.  There are unnecessary DIVs with the class "cleared" that aren't being used for anything.  There are also unneeded `<p>` tags and `<ul>` tags (At the bottom of the about.html page for example.  This is making a bunch of empty white space at the bottom of your pages.

Comment: Thank you for you response. I am going to look into the.. unnecessary tags.

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the HTML on your page you have a  tag with a 
 inside it check line 111 of your html.

You also have an empty  sitting off to the right of you text check line 113.

This is just for the homepage but remove them and you will remove the whitespace that exists after the text and before the footer.

Comment: Hi @Matt I have gone through it. That not the final version of the information there. Its a bit lesser than wat is there. And I want the solution for the complete website. I am unable to locate the option which could get rid of the attribute which is making it to stretch 100% horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting:

```
margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; <---I used this for IE
size: 100%; <---image stretches with any browser
```